# rspec validation failed: NoMethodError and expected <Blah 'foo_id:1'> but Foo_id can't be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have two problems here, both relating to rspec.

1) This NoMethodError, which comes from a `shares` method and an association between `Trade` and `wanted_item` inside `Trade.rb`. See below for my spec/model code, and you'll see that I've defined `wanted_item_id`. Why am I getting a NoMethodError?

```
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `shares' for nil:NilClass
```

2) Every time I put `expect(subject).to be_valid` into a statement, the test fails, saying that it expects the output I describe in the spec, but that it "got errors," and that the field can't be blank. Why does this happen?

```
Failure/Error: expect(subject).to be_valid
  expected #<Trade id: nil, trade_requester_id: 1, wanted_item_id:22> to be valid, but got errors: Trade requester can't be blank, etc, .....
```

---

Here is my test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Trade, type: :model do
    subject { described_class.new }

    it "is valid with valid attributes" do
        subject.trade_requester_id = 1
        subject.wanted_item_id = 22
        subject.shares = 24
        subject.agreement = false
        expect(subject).to be_valid
    end

  it "is valid with a trade_requester" do
        subject.trade_requester_id = 1
        expect(subject).to be_valid
    end

  it "is not valid without a wanted_item" do
    subject.wanted_item_id = 22
    expect(subject).to be_valid
  end
end
```

And here is my model:

```
class Trade < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :trade_requester, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :wanted_item, class_name: "Item"

    validates :trade_requester, :wanted_item, presence: true
    validates :shares, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, 
                                    less_than_or_equal_to: :max_shares }
    validates :agreement, presence: true

    scope :unapproved, -> { where(approved: nil) }
    scope :approved, -> { where(approved: true) }

    def max_shares
        wanted_item.shares
    end
end
```

Comment: It's not enough that the ids are set. The referenced records need to actually exist. Which I guess they don't because it doesn't look like you're creating them in your test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing:

```
NoMethodError
  undefined method `shares' for nil:NilClass
```

because your `subject` is `nil` and the class `Nil` does not have a `shares` method.

You need to setup your `subject` properly. I'm not familiar with the syntax that you're using.

The common pattern to this would be to create factories and have the valid data for the associations ready to go.

Or you could set something up like this:

```
describe Trade do
  let(:trade_requester){ TradeRequester.create(valid attrs) }
  let(:wanted_item    ){ WantedItem.create(valid attrs)     }

  it "is valid with valid attributes" do
    trade = Trade.new(trade_requester: trade_requester, wanted_item: wanted_item, shares: 21)
    expect( trade ).to be_valid
  end
end
```

Comment: when `trade` is created, it will be `valid` always. No use of expecting valid object to `be_valid`. If object is invalid, then it will not be created.

Comment: Yes, you're right. My mistake. You can set the object up with `.new` and then check its validity.